# I need understand how to remove -02:00 in date 2015-01-01T08:00:00-02:00

Tags: java, date, split

In my code I try get hour in String, but I cannot remove the 02:00 in my String.

```
String horaInicio = "2015-01-01T08:00:00-02:00"
   try{
         String[] buffer = null;
         buffer = horaInicio.split("T");
         DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
         dateFormat.parse(buffer[1]);
      }catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    }
```

I cannot remove the -02:00 after hour 08:00. thanks

Comment: The short answer is, don't, it's the TimeZone offset, which is kind of important, instead, you could use a format of `DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");` which will generate a `Date` of `Thu Jan 01 21:00:00 AEDT 2015` (on my PC)

Comment: You could also make use of Java 8's Time API and use `LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(horaInicio, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);` which outputs `2015-01-01T08:00` (on my PC)

Comment: @Lift_Close We gave you several options to keep only `08:00` on the other question you asked. Why are you still struggling with this?